# Total spin of many photon thermal state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, thermal-radiation

I need to find the total spin of a large spin 1/2 ensemble in thermal state:

I'm trying to find a formula for $\operatorname{Tr}(S^2 \rho)$ where $\rho=\frac{1}{Z}e^{\beta S_z}$ is the thermal state of a large number $N$  of spin-1/2 particles at temperature $T=\beta^{-1}$.

Do you know any book where this is done? I have a formula as a sum, but they may be a way to simplify it a bit, knowing $N \gg 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by  $1<<N$?, Where $N$ is a large number.

Comment: In the title you ask about photons, which have spin 1, but then you talk about a 1/2 spin ensemble. Which one?

Comment: Ok, it is just the polarization of the photon which is a spin 1/2. $1<<N$ means N large ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will address the question from the [current body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/268195/1) of the question, asking for $\operatorname{Tr}(S^2\rho)$ on a system of $N$ spin-1/2 particles in the thermal state $\rho = \frac1Ze^{-\beta S_z}$. This has little to do with the photons in the question title.

The total spin operator splits into single-particle terms and two-particle cross terms.
$$
S^2=\mathbf S\cdot\mathbf S = \sum_i s^2_i+\sum_{i\neq j}\left[ s_x^{(i)}s_x^{(j)} + s_y^{(i)}s_y^{(j)} + s_z^{(i)}s_z^{(j)}\right]
$$
Each single-particle term evaluates to a constant, since all the particles have spin 1/2, so $s^2_i=\frac12(\frac12+1)=3/4.$ The cross terms essentially separate, since you can ignore the contributions of all the spins $k\neq i,j$, which means that the $x$ and $y$ cross terms vanish as
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\left(s_x^{(i)}s_x^{(j)}e^{-\beta \left(s_z^{(i)} + s_z^{(j)}\right)} \right)
=
\operatorname{Tr}\left(s_x^{(i)}e^{-\beta s_z^{(i)} } \right)
\operatorname{Tr}\left(s_x^{(j)}e^{-\beta s_z^{(j)} } \right)
=0,
$$
and identically for the $s_y$. The $s_z$, on the other hand, do have a nonzero expectation value, as
$$
\frac{
\operatorname{Tr}\left(s_ze^{-\beta s_z } \right)
}{
\operatorname{Tr}\left(e^{-\beta s_z } \right)
}
=
\frac{\frac12 e^{-\beta/2} - \frac12 e^{\beta/2} }{e^{\beta/2}+e^{-\beta/2}}
=-\frac12 \tanh(\beta/2),
$$
and you have $N(N-1)$ pairs contributing the square of this to $⟨S^2⟩$. This means, then, that your final expectation value is

$$
⟨S^2⟩
=
\frac1Z\operatorname{Tr}\left(S^2e^{-\beta S_z}\right)
=
\frac34 N + \frac14\tanh^2(\beta/2) N(N-1).
$$
If you then want to do thermodynamics on this, then you can take $N\gg1$ straight away, but then this makes the $\beta\to 0$ limit meaningless, so it's up to you to fiddle with exactly what quantities you need.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to change the title...